# Swarm Robotics Simulator

Tags: simulation

I want to do an academic project in Swarm Robotics. Which software is more suitable for implementing swarm robotics(Swarm Intelligence) algorithms in easy way? I am comfortable with C, Python, and MATLAB. Please recommend a free software to do this project.